# I suggest that the API doc on Authentication be edited

Tags: bug, api, wording

http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication has a really awkward sentence that I think may be missing something.

Perhaps

> The most obvious work around, making authentication site-centric instead of network wide, would solve this it would make user's with accounts on multiple sites experience much worse.

was meant to be

> The most obvious work around, making authentication site-centric instead of network wide, would solve this, but it would degrade the experience of users with accounts on multiple sites.

Comment: While we're at it, fix the rest of the sentence too. Look at this: "user's with accounts on multiple sites experience". It would be much less confusing to say "the experience of users with accounts on multiple sites".

Comment: Good point. I'll Suggest "degrade the experience of users with accounts on multiple sites".